# How to access SQLite DB from IIS hosted WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqlite, wcf, iis

I am trying to deploy a WCF service that uses a SQLite DB to read some data as well as connecting to another Database (MS SQL). The service itself is consumed by a ASP Web site running on the same server.

The problem is that only my user is able to fully use the website and service. Every other user can't seem to open the sqlite database file.

What kind of permissions or special access do you need to access a sqlite database from IIS?

The Application pool is setup with a domain account so that access to the MS SQL Database can be granted (Integrated Security).

The folder where the database is stored is accessible by the account. And I've even tried to make it accessible by Everyone and all users with no luck.

I feel I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what...

**Update:** The error is as follows:

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

*Inner Exception:*

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException

Unable to open database file.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The error is could not open provider.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, I'm going to document it here for posterity. I took a few steps to do so, and I currently don't have the environment set up to be able to reproduce the issue consistently and quickly, so I'm not entirely sure which was the actual solution.

Disclaimer aside, here are my changes:

1. I created a new Application Pool and Website on IIS, on another directory entirely, not on "C:\inetpub\wwwroot". I used "C:\Sites\MySite" to deploy both my WCF service and the website which consumed it.
2. I changed the application pool identity account to a new AD Service account.
3. I placed the database inside of the Service Web App directory, within a directory called data. I removed all inherited permissions from the directory and the database file, and gave the both the service account and Everyone Full Control of the directory and database file.
4. I edited the connection string for sqlite to have the setting "Journal Mode=Off;".
5. I stopped and started both the Application Pool and the WebSite on IIS.

After this the service worked correctly, and I was able to access both the database file and the connection to SQL Server. If I get the opportunity, I would set up some kind of virtual network to replicate this and see if I could figure out exactly what caused the error in the first place.